# Free a single-use variable after returning it

Tags: c, memory-management, scope, lifetime

I have a function that is supposed to listen for input on a Windows console. It uses conio.h. It will get called about 20 times per second.

How can I prevent my memory getting clogged up? As far as I understand C, it will initialize a new char every time. I can't use a single common memory location. The function has to be completely self-encapsulated.

Is there an easier way to remove `in` from memory after returning it, besides also returning its memory adress and calling `free(*adress)`?

Code:

```c
#include <conio.h>

// Passively listen for input, return char if input, else 0
char listen() {
    char in = 0;

    if (kbhit()) { // Some key was pressed
        in = getch(); // Which key?
    }

    return in;
}

void forward(void);

// Usage, for instance control a figure in a game
void main(void) {
    while (game) {
        char input = listen()

        if (input == 'w')
            forward();
    }
}
```

Comment: Compilers are smart, they don't allocate memory each time a function is called, it only reuses old memory (in this case the stack). Therefore it doesn't matter how many times you call a function, if it doesn't explicitly allocate memory itself then your memory usage should be fixed and static.

Comment: There is no problem: `char in` is a local variable and as such will be stored on the stack, and automatically "freed" when the function returns. So you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Your memory will not get "clogged up" with the above code. The variable storage in function `listen` will disappear when the function returns. The `input` variable in the `while` loop in `main` will be re-used every time around the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there an easier way to remove in from memory after returning it*

You don't need to worry, for the variables with block scope and automatic storage duration, once the scope is over, their lifetime is also over and memory can be reclaimed automatically. As a programmer, you don't have to take any additional action.

That said, any half-decent compiler will optimize the code to something like the below to avoid the usage of any temporary variable, altogether.

```
char listen() {

    if (kbhit()) { // Some key was pressed
        return getch(); // Which key?
    }
   return 0;
}
```

That said, `getch()` returns an `int`, so you should better change the return type of the `listen()` function to return an `int` value, too.